# Passing variables from one swift file to another

Tags: swift, file, variables

Let's say I have 3 swift files:

```
fileOne.swift
fileTwo.swift
vars.swift
```

and let's say that my vars.swift file looks like this:

```
let let1 = "this is let one"
var isItTrue = false
```

How can I setup my code in fileOne.swift and fileTwo.swift so that I can access and modify the variables contained within the vars.swift file?

Comment: Just a note: I am attempting to do this across view controllers in an iOS app. Using a single file to store my variables would make my life much easier especially when it comes to saving the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If  `vars.swift` a file from where you will access constants you can create the constants in a struct and then access them from the other file

```
struct Constants {
    static let v1 = "var1"
}
```

file1.swift

```
class File1 {

  func test() {
    print( Constants.v1);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `vars.swift` file *really* says `let let1=...` right at the top level of the file, you can just access `let1` from anywhere; all Swift files can see one another, and `let1` is a global constant. Similarly for `var isItTrue`; it is a global variable and any code anywhere can see it and set it.

If what you mean is that `vars.swift` contains a class declaration with instance variables, then you need to get a reference to an instance in order to set those variables. You need to learn about *object-oriented programming* (which is what you're doing when you use Swift).

Answer (score 0):

Vars.swift

```
struct Vars {
    static let key1 = "value1"
    static let key2 = "value2"
}
```

Use:

```
Vars.key1
```